# How to download files from AWS s3 storage on schedule using Github actions?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cron, github-actions

I've some small files to download from AWS S3 storage on a specific schedule. The limitation is that I need to use Github Actions to get them, so no external scripts. I realise it's possible to send a file **from** Github **to** AWS S3 using a Github Action but what about the other way around?

The files are just monthly generated metadata.json files, nothing massive. Each month there is a new one created and I need to grab the last 3 most recent for reporting. Ultimately I'd want to automatically convert it to .csv also and possibly join them into one larger.json, but I don't need to do anything else special with them.

I can find dozens of examples of sending files to S3 on a schedule but not receiving.

Comment: Do you have a cloudfront configured to download those file with a curl command? And why not using a script with Github Actions? You can store it in the repository and use it to download the jsons and generate the larger one.